# Spring Data Mongo DB Criteria query to filter nested documents based on condition

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, spring-mongo

I am working on fetching documents which has nested documents also to it using Spring Data Mongo.
I am trying to get documents and include nested documents to it if a particular condition matches or give me just the parent document alone. I need the parent document and nested document which matches condition if any of the replies, isApproved status is true or else just get the parent document alone.
Below is the sample data set ,

```
Sample Data Set:
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5efe3d1f8a2ef008249f72d9"),
"_class" : "com.text.TestInfo",
"discussion_id" : "5efcbbdee87e6d1a706d3a4a",
"content" : "edited comment",
"title" : "Test",
"isApproved" : true,
"replies" : [
  {
  "_id" : ObjectId("59nts64j3cdcds3449f72d9"),
  "content" : "Sample text",
  "isApproved" : false
  },
  {
  "_id" : ObjectId("0j93k099vcdkfdf3vdf372d9"),
  "content" : "Sample text",
  "isApproved" : true
  }   
  ]
 },
 {
"_id" : ObjectId("5efe3d189ms908249f72d9"),
"_class" : "com.text.TestInfo",
"discussion_id" : "5efcbbdee87e6d1a706d3a4a",
"content" : "new eidted comment",
"title" : "Test",
"isApproved" : true,
"replies" : [
  {
  "_id" : ObjectId("59nts64j3cdcds3449f72d9"),
  "content" : "Sample text",
  "isApproved" : false
  }
  ]
 },
 {
"_id" : ObjectId("5efe390d9sds249f72d9"),
"_class" : "com.text.TestInfo",
"discussion_id" : "5efcbbdee87e6d1a706d3a4a",
"content" : "new eidted comment",
"title" : "Test",
"isApproved" : false,
"replies" : [
  {
  "_id" : ObjectId("59nts64j3cdcds3449f72d9"),
  "content" : "dasdsatext",
  "isApproved" : true
  }
  ]
 }
```

So, above is the data set in one document there is two sub-document and in
next one there is only one sub-document. Below is the expected output.

```
Expected Output:
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5efe3d1f8a2ef008249f72d9"),
"_class" : "com.text.TestInfo",
"discussion_id" : "5efcbbdee87e6d1a706d3a4a",
"content" : "edited comment",
"title" : "Test",
"isApproved" : true,
"replies" : [
  {
  "_id" : ObjectId("0j93k099vcdkfdf3vdf372d9"),
  "content" : "Sample text",
  "isApproved" : true
  }   
  ]
},
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5efe3d189ms908249f72d9"),
"_class" : "com.text.TestInfo",
"discussion_id" : "5efcbbdee87e6d1a706d3a4a",
"content" : "new eidted comment",
"title" : "Test",
"replies" : []
}
```

Below are the 2 ways which I have tried using Spring Data MongoDB

```
First Way:
Query query = new Query();
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria().andOperator(Criteria.where("discussion_id").
    is(new ObjectId("5efe3d1f8a2ef008249f72d9"))).and("replies").elemMatch(Criteria.where("isApproved").ne(true));
    query.addCriteria(criteria);
    List<TestInfo> listOfInfos = mongoOps.find(query, TestInfo.class);
```

What I received as a result is first document completely alone which doesn't suffice my requirement.

```
Second Way:
Query query = new Query();
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria().andOperator(Criteria.where("discussion_id").
    is(new ObjectId("5efe3d1f8a2ef008249f72d9")));
    query.addCriteria(criteria);
    query.fields().elemMatch(Criteria.where("isApproved").ne(true));
    List<TestInfo> listOfInfos = mongoOps.find(query, TestInfo.class);
```

Here the output is only the reply sub document present in first document parent document values are coming as null.

Kindly, let me know the what is the mistake I made

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `$project`. To return only the matched array element, use `replies.$`

[play](https://mongoplayground.net/p/pBM1cQMdEsb)

```
db.collection.find({
  "replies.isApproved": false
},
{
  "replies.$": 1,
  "_class": 1,
  "discussion_id": 1
})
```

To get other elements where array doesn't have match:

[play](https://mongoplayground.net/p/M4UZvastKP3)

```
db.collection.find({},
{
  "replies": {
    $elemMatch: {
      "isApproved": false
    }
  },
  "_class": 1,
  "discussion_id": 1
})
```

**Edit:**

[play](https://mongoplayground.net/p/DONhtvPeGJ2)

```
db.collection.find({
  "isApproved": false
},
{
  "replies": {
    $elemMatch: {
      "isApproved": false
    }
  },
  "_class": 1,
  "discussion_id": 1
})
```

Comment: if no replies approved value is false I need the parent document alone also, But this code doesn't return that expected result.

Comment: I have made a edit by adding a new field as isApproved in parent document which I forgot to mention. According to your example in play , I need result only if any parent document has a isApproved value equal to false if it's true I don't need that document. If the value  of isApproved from parent document is false , I need parent document record with sub-documents record where isApproved value is false. If sub-documents have a record of isApproved value as false but parent record isApproved value is true I don't want the complete record in result.

Comment: any help please @Gibbs

Comment: Your conditions are bit confusing. Can you elaborate little detailed?

Comment: For example I have parent document with "isApproved : false" and some sub-documents with "isApproved : false" and "isApproved:true". The result I need here is Parent document with sub-documents only where "isApproved : false". If Parent document has "isApproved:true" but has few sub-documents where "isApproved:false". Here I dont want the document in result since I need document only when Parent document has "isApproved:false". If Parent document has "isApproved:false" but no sub-documents "isApproved:false" , Here I need parent record alone without sub-documents. Does it make sense?

Comment: your answer is helpful but where do you use project keyword in query. And how can we write this query in java?

Comment: I would suggest you to tryout in java and post a question for unsolvable errors.project is the second object in that query. Implicitly it is project.